# How to change the x-axis unit in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have data of x-axis from 0 to 700 hours. Each hour has data. But I want to show day as a unit for my x-axis. Currently, the x-axis is like `[1..2..3...713]` . 
But I want them to be like `[1..5..10..15...29]`. I still want to plot all the individual 24 hours values between days instead of hours in x-axis. I just want to show days . How can I do this in matplotlib?